# How to get a list of available resource names in FireMonkey Android application?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

We may add resources in `Project | Resources and Images...`.  We may load the resource at runtime if we use a resource name.

How may I show a list of names for resources added for FireMonkey/Android application?  We use `EnumResNameProc` for application in Windows platform.